# How to save values when i click previous button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created online exam application (web based) in asp.net c#. In my application first form includes dropdownlist for tests & start button. When i select particular test from dropdownlist & after clicking to start button it goes to the next page. It includes one label for question, radiobuttonlist for answers, next & previous button.In first form in the click event of start button i have created non repeated random values ( for question ids) i.e stored in array.when it redirects to another page then 1st question from that array will display with answers & after clicking next button next question will appear, here i have inserted selected values(answers selected in radiobuttonlist) by user in database to calculate score. Problem is with previous button, when i click to previous button then it goes to previous button but i want earlier selected values by user to be bind with that radiobuttonlist. how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are storing the previous question answer in your database or somewhere else.

Then in the `page_load` event check the database with the question number and if the records available then display the user selection accordingly by fetching them from the database.

Comment: ok i did that but i am getting problem as when i click previous button & then next button then in next click also value to be selected( as earlier this value selected by user). here i have written code for inserting selected values by user in next button and selected those values (code) in previous click

Comment: @nirmal now it comes selected value(in radiobuttonlist) from database when i click previous button but suppose i click next button two times then it wil insert 2 records for the same question ids

Comment: i have written code in for inserting those values in next button what should changes i do?

Comment: In the Next button, before inserting you should check if the record already exists then just update the value instead of the insertion

Comment: ok. how to check if that value exists or not i used if exists(field1.value) but its not working. let me know which method should i use to check existing value

Comment: Can you please post few codes, what you are trying to do? If you are storing the values in the database then of course you can do that with the SQL queries.

Comment: int t = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]);

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Sel_Ans VALUES ('1', @Quid, @Selected, '1')", sqlconn);
                    SqlParameter Quid = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quid", SqlDbType.Int, 50);                
                    Quid.Value = a[t - 2];
                    SqlParameter Selected = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Selected", SqlDbType.Int, 50);
                    Selected.Value = rb;
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlconn.Close();

Comment: this is for inserting values in database how do i check with Quid value already exists or not

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT selected from Sel_Ans WHERE Quid=@Quid", sqlconn); var result=cmd.ExecuteScalar(); If (result!=DBnull.value){  cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Sel_Ans Set Selected=@Selected WHERE Quid=@Quid", sqlconn); cmd.ExecutenonQuery();} else { // Put your insert code here }

Comment: here its going in update query even there is no record in SelAns table i.e  If (result!=DBnull.value) condition results in true but actually there is no record in selans table then also it gives if condition as true it sholud be false here

Comment: If (result!=DBnull.value) this condition is not working may i know other solution

Comment: Please take a look, what is the result value is. You can also try with if(result!=null)

Comment: before i run my project, table SelAns table is blank so the If (result!=DBnull.value)- this condition should not be true as no values inside result but it gives true. why so?